# Can Tensors on different devices add together?

Tags: pytorch, device

I found a curious thing recently. As far as I know, when you want to do some operations on two tensors, you should make sure that they are on the same device. But when I write my code like this, it runs unexpectly

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor(1, device='cuda')
print(a.device)
b = torch.tensor(2, device='cpu')
print(b.device)
torch(a+b)


cuda:0
cpu
tensor(3, device='cuda:0')
```

And it can't work in my code like this:

```py
pts_1_tile = torch.tensor([[0], [0]], dtype=torch.float32)
torch.add(pred_4pt_shift, pts_1_tile)
```

[image]

here `pred_4pt_shift` is an intermediate result of a sub-Net, and it is a tensor on GPU.
My question is that why the first code can work but the second one reports this different device error?

Comment: Here, you should remove torch: a + b

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean `print(a+b)` rather than `torch(a+b)`.

Scalar tensor is a special case which could be automatically moved to target device.
If you define `a` and `b` as 1-d tensor, it will error out:

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1], device='cuda')
b = torch.tensor([2], device='cpu')
print(a+b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```